# How to integrate Mailchimp api into my iOS Swift app

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, mailchimp

I have an app I created in Swift with my database built with Parse. I know how to export data from Parse and update my subscriber list for Mailchimp, but how do I have my app automatically update that list when a user creates a new account? I've been researching how but I haven't come across anything that can help me yet. Also everything seems to be in Objective-C. I've used bridging headers before, but I don't know if that will be necessary or not. Any guidance would be a lot of help!

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to hook into this API endpoint that's part of the Mailchimp API...

https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/2.0/lists/batch-subscribe.php

Comment: MailChimp just announced that v2 would be decommissioned at the end of the year, so you probably don't want this.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I wouldn't do this. It would require you to distribute your MailChimp API key with your app, which would give any person who downloaded that app full control over your account.

You'll either want a back-end service that connects to MailChimp or look into IFTTT or Zapier for Parse and MailChimp integrations.

Comment: Thanks Pete. This is my first app so this helps a lot. However, neither of those 2 services integrate with Parse.. Hmmm.. Is this not common practice to automatically sign up new users to a MailChimp list straight from the app? Or is it Parse that is confusing to these services?